# Increase number of splits for SequenceFileInputFormat

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, mapreduce, sequencefile

I'm using **SequenceFileInputFormat** as my input for my map, where the key is text and the value is text. There are **106 files** each of them is between 500 MB to 750 MB. I saw my logs and it says there that the **number of splits is 290**.

I want to know if there is a way to **increase the number of splits**, because my jobs are taking a lot of time to run. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the number of splits by reducing the maximum size for each split, using the `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` property. The value to set is the maximum split size in bytes.

Comment: Thank you, whats the minimum that I can set this property to?